I use the win32print library to print on a thermal printer. I want to print images, but it does not print and does not give me any errors
from escpos import printer
import tkinter as tk
import win32print
from PIL import Image, ImageWin,ImageOps

hPrinter = win32print.OpenPrinter("XP-80")

current_job = win32print.StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, ("hello world", None, "RAW"))

win32print.StartPagePrinter(hPrinter)

win32print.WritePrinter(hPrinter, b'Hellos World\n')

win32print.StartPagePrinter(hPrinter)

image_path = "D:\\ppp\\aldy\\python\\Sorting\\assets\\2e82177f-2306-4357-b1f5-453b6928167c.png"

img_original = Image.open(image_path)

if img_original.mode == 'RGBA':

    r, g, b, a = img_original.split()

    mask = a
else:
    mask = img_original.convert('L')  # Convert to grayscale

img_original = img_original.convert('RGBA')
width, height = img_original.size

im = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), (255,255,255,255))

im.paste(img_original,mask=mask)

im = im.convert('L')

im = ImageOps.invert(im)

im = im.convert("1")

im = im.transpose(Image.ROTATE_270).transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)

line_height = 24

width_pixels, height_pixels = im.size

top= 0

left = 0

while left < width_pixels:

    box = (left, top,left + line_height, top + height_pixels)

    im_slice = im.crop(box)

    im_bytes = im_slice.tobytes()

    win32print.WritePrinter(hPrinter, im_bytes)

    left += line_height

win32print.EndPagePrinter(hPrinter)

win32print.EndDocPrinter(hPrinter)

def close():

    global hPrinter  # Declare hPrinter as global

    if hPrinter:

        win32print.ClosePrinter(hPrinter)

        hPrinter = None

